# create new document from template

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, word-template

I want to open a new document from a MS-Word template from my Java-App, but only manage to edit the template itself.

Here is my situation:
Inside my Jar file is a word template, that gets copied to a user-specified location, so he/she can edit it. Afterwards, the application can open this edited template, insert data into it and open it in word. This all works fine (using Apache-POI), but the last step is not entirely what I want.

Normally, when double-clicking a word-template, Word would open a NEW document (titled Document1) that is not saved anywhere yet. In my case, Word opens the word-template for editing (titled blablaMyTemplate), meaning the already saved template from which documents should be created. How do I manage to open a newly created document from the template using Java?

This is my code (try/catch and stream closing omitted):

```
    File bbb = new File(new File(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath()).getParentFile().getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + "/blablaMyTemplate.dotx");
    if (!bbb.exists()) { //copy file to outside of jar for user editing
        Files.copy(Buchungsbegleitblatt.class.getResourceAsStream("bbb.dotx"), bbb.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
    File tmp = File.createTempFile("bbb", ".dotx"); //create tmp file to insert data
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(bbb);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tmp);
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(in);
    //here, some data is filled into the document using Apache-POI (omitted, because it works fine)
    document.write(out);
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(tmp); //this opens the template for editing, it does not create a new doc from template
    }
```

The issue lies within the last line, but I have no idea what else I could call here.

To make it a little clearer, here is an image of the context menu I get on the template file and what is supposed to happen:

[image: context menu on template]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have exactly described the problem already. `Desktop.open` will exactly do what it says. It will perform the `open` event for the called application which is assigned to the file type.

What you need is to perform the `new` event. This can be achieved in `Word` using [startup command-line switches to start Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/210565).

In the linked knowledge base entry you can find:

> ...
>
> `/ttemplate_name     Starts Word with a new document based on a template
>                      other than the Normal template.`
>
> ...

To do so with `Java` either `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` or `ProcessBuilder` can be used. With both I would recommend first to start the command interpreter `CMD` as a shell and use the `start` command from this to start the application. So we avoid the need to know the exact path to the application.

Examples:

```
import java.io.*;

class RuntimeExec {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
        // Execute a command as a single line
        File f = new File("C:/Users/axel/Documents/The Template.dotx");
        System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
        String cmd = "cmd /C start winword.exe /t\"" + f.getAbsolutePath() + "\"";
        Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

  }
}

class UseProcessBuilder {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
        //use ProcessBuilder to have more control
        File f = new File("C:/Users/axel/Documents/The Template.dotx");
        System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
        String application = "winword.exe";
        String switchNewFromTemplate = "/t";
        String file = f.getAbsolutePath(); 
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/C", "start", application, switchNewFromTemplate+file);
        Process process = pb.start();

      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
}
```

---

There is one possibility to not explicitly start the `winword` application. The `start` command has the feature to perform the default action according to the file extension with the given file if we give a empty string `""` as the application name:

`start "" "The name of the file.ext"`

Example:

`start "" "The name of the file.dotx"`

This will perform the default action `new` in `winword` application which is related to the `dotx` extension in registry database.

So:

```
class RuntimeExec {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
        // Execute a command as a single line
        File f = new File("C:/Users/Axel Richter/Documents/The Template.dotx");
        System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
        String cmd = "cmd /C start \"\" \"" + f.getAbsolutePath() + "\"";
        Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

        InputStream in = child.getErrorStream();
        int c;
        while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char)c);
        }
        in.close();

      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

  }
}

class UseProcessBuilder {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
        //use ProcessBuilder to have more control
        File f = new File("C:/Users/Axel Richter/Documents/The Template.dotx");
        System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
        String file = f.getAbsolutePath(); 
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/C", "start", "\"\"", file);
        Process process = pb.start();

        InputStream in = process.getErrorStream();
        int c;
        while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char)c);
        }
        in.close();

      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works, thank you very much! I just have a slight follow up question: is there any way to detect if winword.exe actually exists? If it doesn't, an error is obviously thrown ("windord.exe could not be found", or something), but the process returns '1' for any error I was able to produce (for example: access denied), so I can't go only on that...

Comment: What is the aim? Avoiding the Windows error message? This will be not possible. For this we would have to examine the whole Windows system whether the application is installed or not **before** we try to start it. Otherwise, the `ProcessBuilder` can redirect the Error stream together with the output stream to a file. Or you could get the Error stream from the `Process` using  `process.getErrorStream();` and read from this.

Comment: They aim would be to go about it as follows: check if MSWord is properly installed and, if so, launch a new document from the template using the `ProcessBuilder`, otherwise create a saved document from the template in a temporary folder and open it regularly using `Desktop.open(...)` (for example using LibreOffice, or whatever the user has installed).

I'll play around a bit and see what I can manage with `process.getErrorStream();`. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @user2336377: See my supplement.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want :) Thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to start a process on the template so that Windows will handle the opening, and use the default intent. It's been a while since I've touched Java, but if it's like C# it will be something like `new Process(tmp).Start()`.

Though, I'm not really sure if this is what you're looking for, exactly.

Comment: Thats exactly what the last line does... It calls the native OS (in this case Windows) to open the specified file. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open-java.io.File-

Comment: It does kind of sound that way. It also kind of sounds like it might skip the intent part. Worth trying `Process` imo.

Comment: I've never done much with C#, but I don't think the Java `Process` is the same as the C# one. At least I have no idea how I would go about just passing the file to it and starting it like you stated.^^